# "Attack on all of humanity" or "attack against humanity": which is better?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

Hello ladies and gentlemen, this is Semin from Turkey. I'm wondering which of the following is better in terms of grammar and meaning:

> I strongly condemn the terrorist attacks in Brussels. Regardless of
>   where or by whom, terrorism is an attack **on all of** humanity

OR

> I strongly condemn the terrorist attacks in Brussels. Regardless of
>   where or by whom, terrorism is an attack **against** humanity

Comment: They're both grammatically correct; the former implies that the attack is against every single human, while the latter brings to mind "crimes against humanity". What message do you want to connote?

Comment: Definitely the second one Alex, I tried to say that the "humanity" is affected after all. Not individuals one by one. Thank you:)

Comment: Cool. Will convert to answer so that others may benefit.

Comment: Hello Semin, welcome to Stack Exchange! I've edited your question to try to emphasize the difference between your two options. Please review my edit to check that it still reflects what you wanted to learn. Also, please be aware that general proofreading questions are not allowed on this site. You need to ask about some particular word, phrase or grammatical principle. Something else you should know: we do have an [English Language Learners site](http://ell.stackexchange.com); if you are currently learning English, I would suggest that you ask questions there in the future.

Answer (score 2):

They're both grammatically correct; the former implies that the attack is against every single human, while the latter brings to mind "crimes against humanity".

You've indicated that you intend the latter meaning, so "an attack against humanity" is more appropriate.